# Comparing text in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula

I'm using Excel 2010. The problem is that I need to extract hours in a time sheet based on employee names. I am using something like this: `=SUMIFS(........timesheet!$D:$D,"*Tom*")`. This works, but I would like this to work with the cell location, such as `(...timesheet!$D:$D,Q1)`. Any suggestions on converting Q1 so it looks like "Tom". Thanks

Comment: On the surface it sounds like you can just type "Tom" - without the quotes - into Q1, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I often create summary tables (e.g. TOM's hours) using the `=SUMPRODUCT()`function in Excel. If you have a table with all the hours recorded that looks similar to the following:

```
  G    H
1 Name hours
2 Tom  5
3 Mike 3
4 Tom  3
```

Then you can create a table like:

```
  1     2
A Tom   8
B Mike  3
```

In the second column you put the formula:

```
=sumproduct(--(A1=$G$2:$G$4),$H$2:$H$4)
```

What this essentially does is that it returns a 1 if the row in the two tables match and multiplies it with the second column (first table) and then returns the sum of everything. If there is no match then it returns a 0. In this case it multiplies 0 * 5 = 0.

Comment: +1 for using the double unary operator. You can consider changing the formula a bit to `=SUMPRODUCT((A1=$G$2:$G$4) * ($H$2:$H$4))`, in which case you do not have to use the unary operator anymore; furthermore it gives you more flexibility when creating more complex formulas using SUMPRODUCT().